# Symfony3 setAction in FormType

Tags: symfony

In symfony2 I was able to call

```
// MyController.php
$formType = new MyFormType($this->container);
$form = $this->createForm($formType); 

// MyFormType.php
protected $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->setAction($this
            ->container
            ->get('router')
            ->generate('myAction')
        );
    // ...
    }
}
```

In symfony3 I should pass `string` to `createForm` method, so I am not able to pass controller or router to to `MyFormType`

I tried to define FormType as a service, but it does not changed the behavior.

How can I set action in `MyFormType` (not in the `MyController`)?

Comment: Show how you defined the form type as a service.  You should be able to inject the router without a problem.

Comment: Yes, I injected router without a problem, but it seems to me, that symfony creates form type as `new FormType`, not calling service at all (when using `createForm` method). So my constructor in FormType is called without any params.

Comment: Nope.  If you have your form type properly defined as a service then the createForm functionality will pull it from the container.  Check your work carefully.  Make sure your service definitions are being loaded using container:debug.  I promise that it will work.

Comment: I defined service as it was described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services and it is currently in debug:container output, but FormType constructor is called without any params

Comment: Well it is your choice.  But defining form types as services is very useful.  You still have something configured wrong.  If you posted your service definition then maybe we could spot the error.  And of course your should not be using the new MyFormType() operator anywhere.  Just the class name.

Comment: I cannot format it in comment, but here it is: `app.form.type.viewing_signup:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ViewingSignupType
        arguments: [ "@service_container" ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }`

Comment: Just update your question.  By the way, if you happen to have a typo in your 'class:' parameter then it will fail silently.  So double check that.

Comment: No, no typos, I also checked debug - it's ok there. Seems that symfony does not call service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and the only option I found at the moment is:

```
// MyController.php
$this->createForm(MyFormType::class, null, ['router' => $this->get('router')]);

// MyFormType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setAction($options['router']->generate('myAction'));
    // ...
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'router' => null,
        // ...
    ]);
}
```

But this solution seems a little bit ugly for me.

Answer (score 2):

At least in Symfony2 (tested in 2.7), you can do that:

```
//MyController.php
$this->createForm(MyFormType::class, null, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('my_acton_name')));
```

With this solution no need to modify your FormType, the option 'action' is a real option supported by Symfony Forms, so no need to add it using the router.
You can find the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#action).

Comment: It's almost the same as in my answer. The difference is that I passed router, not the url. I do not want to store the url in controller, it's not the good practice.

Comment: Indeed this is almost the same as your, the difference is I used a built-in functionality. The both are possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your form as service, e.g.:

```js
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/MyFormType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // You can now use myService.
        $builder
            ->setAction(
                $this->router->generate('myAction')
            )
            ->add('myInput')
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

```yaml
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.form.type.my_form_type:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\MyFormType
        arguments: [ "@router" ]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

In your controller then you just call `$this->createForm(MyFormType::class);`

Comment: I tried exactly what you wrote, I will not post all the classes here, as there are too much code. In symfony2 (some time earlier) I used this way of defining FormTypes (services.yml) and it worked, but in sf3 I got none in MyFormType constructor :(